# Is there a way to determine the graphics memory footprint of an OpenGL texture or of a QOpenGLTexture?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

Is there a way to determine the graphics memory footprint of an OpenGL texture?

If not, is there a way to determine the graphics memory footprint of a QOpenGLTexture object?

Comment: "*If not, is there a way to determine the graphics memory footprint of a QOpenGLTexture object?*" ... huh? If you can't tell how much memory an OpenGL texture takes from outside of OpenGL, how could a Qt wrapper around that object be able to tell?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean by memory footprint, but textures are typically stored uncompressed in VRAM, therefore you can calculate the memory usage from the resolution and type of texture (see [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/5177))

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the absolute minimum memory that a texture would require by multiplying the texture's size by the bytes-per-pixel of its internal format. This must be done for each mipmap level, and you add all of them up. But that will tell you nothing about any implementation-specific padding that may be needed for the texture's data storage.

So at best, this will be an estimate.